# TypeError: Cannot convert undefined value to object, js engine: hermes

Tags: android, react-native

This is my **App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import Home from './components/Home';
import Details from './components/Details';
import Liked from './components/Liked';
import Profile from './components/Profile';

import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';



const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

const TabNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
      <Tab.Screen name='Liked' component={Liked} />
      <Tab.Screen name='Profile' component={Profile} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  )
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name='TabNavigator' component={TabNavigator} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I redownloaded node modules and nothing have changed.

const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

When I tried to comment above lines error disappear.
What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Your import of createStackNavigator is wrong, it should be `@react-navigation/stack` instead of `react-navigation/stack`